# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\sin(ax)}{(x^2+b^2)^2}dx$ using a D-contour

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x\sin(ax)}{(x^2+b^2)^2}dx$

I need to show that this is equal to $\frac{\pi ae^{-ab}}{2b}$, by considering the contour integral around a D-contour of the function $f(z)=\frac{ze^{iaz}}{(z^2+b^2)^2}$.

In evaluating this integral, I felt that I had taken the right steps, but I appear to keep getting an extra factor of $i$ in the final result. Here's what I have.

I split the integral into two parts, one for the real axis between $-X$ and $X$, and the other for the semicircular part of which I argue away the contribution:

$|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z) dz|\le\frac{\pi X}{(X^2-b^2)^2}\to0$ as $X\to\infty$

Now, this integral has double poles at $z=\pm ib$. I calculate the residue at $z=ib$ as this is in the contour.

$Res(f,z_0=ib)=\lim_{z\to ib}\frac{d}{dz}(z-ib)^2\frac{(z-ib)^2ze^{iaz}}{(z+ib)^2(z-ib)^2}$

$=\lim_{z\to ib}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{ze^{iaz}}{(z+ib)^2}$

$=\lim_{z\to ib}\frac{(z+ib)^2(iaze^{iaz}+e^{iaz})-2ze^{iaz}(z+ib)}{(z+ib)^4}$

$=\lim_{z\to ib}\frac{(z+ib)(iaze^{iaz}+e^{iaz})-2ze^{iaz}}{(z+ib)^3}$

$=\frac{-abe^{-ab}+e^{-ab}(2ib)-2ibe^{-ab}}{(2ib)^3}$

$=\frac{-2iab^2e^{-ab}}{-8ib^3}$

$=\frac{ae^{-ab}}{4b}$

In the final step, I apply the residue theorem, whence I multiply this result by $2\pi i$, giving $\frac{i\pi ae^{-ab}}{2b}$. Where must I have gone wrong to get this extra factor of $i$ which I don't want?

Comment: Third equality from bottom... $-2abe^{-ab}$ term remains on numerator.

Comment: It is simple without complex analysis and contour integration.

Comment: You forgot to take the imaginary part of the equation containing the contour integral of $f(z)$ and the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=ib$.

Answer (score 1):

The residue is right $Res(f,z_0)=\frac{ae^{-ab}}{4b}$ where $z_0=ib$. You probably forgot the $i$ here; When you integrate on the real  line:  $$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) \ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{xcos(ax)}{(x^2+b^2)^2}(=0) + i(!)\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{xsin(ax)}{(x^2+b^2)^2} = 2 \pi i(!) Res(f,z_0) $$
You observe that the first part is $0$ since is an odd function and the integration domain is symmetric to the origin. The second is what you want, you simply forgot to simplify the $i$ here.(!)